# I can't create a view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, view

I'm new in Laravel and I'm trying to create a View in Acelle (app based on Laravel). I read a lot of tutorials, but I've not been luck with this problem.

I created the view "lol.blade.php" on /resources/views folder with this code:

```
HELLO (just hello)
```

The Route:

```
Route::get('lol', function()
{
    if (view()->exists('lol')) {
        //return 'helloooo'; <--- it works
        return view('lol');
    } else {
        return 'not exists';    
    }
});
```

The code knows the view exists, but the url (localhost/acelle/public/lol) prints this message:

**"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."**

I can't solve the problem with tutorials. I followed all the steps about creating views in Laravel, but I don't know why the view prints that message.

Please help!

PS: Laravel version: 5.2.45

**EDIT**:
In console [network] shows **Error 500**. and **laravel.log** prints 59 lines. but the first line show: 
    [2017-07-14 14:08:20] production.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined index:controller in /home/acelle/public_html/acelle/app/Providers/AppServiceProv‌​ider.php:20

Comment: `Whoops, looks like something went wrong` is __insufficient__ description. Asnwer to your question in this case is `fix something`.

Comment: can you post your debug stack. should be just below that `whoops` message

Comment: And if it's not just below that, turn `APP_DEBUG` to `true` in your `.env` file.

Comment: (Alternatively, the error details are likely also in `storage/logs/laravel.log` - a "Whoops" message always has a fairly useful error message *somewhere*)

Comment: Are you sure that your URL is correct? Typically in laravel, a route defined `'lol'` corresponds to a url `'localhost/lol'`. Also, I consider it best practices to have routes defined `'/lol'`. Just my preference.

Comment: @Trojan404 A missing route would throw a 404, not a whoops, I believe.

Comment: in console [network] shows error 500. and laravel.log prints 59 lines. but the first line show:
[2017-07-14 14:08:20] production.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined index: controller in /home/acelle/public_html/acelle/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:20

Comment: Can you show your `AppServiceProvider.php` file content? If it's not big

Comment: @xperator code:
lines 17-25:
app('view')->composer('*', function ($view) {
            $action = app('request')->route()->getAction();
            $controller = class_basename($action['controller']);
            list($controller, $action) = explode('@', $controller);
            $view->with(compact('controller', 'action'));
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted this in the comments:

```
app('view')->composer('*', function ($view) {
    $action = app('request')->route()->getAction();
    $controller = class_basename($action['controller']);
    list($controller, $action) = explode('@', $controller);
    $view->with(compact('controller', 'action'));
});
```

Your issue is that *this* route uses a *closure*, and has **no** controller:

```
Route::get('lol', function() {});
```

Therefore, `$action['controller']` doesn't exist and throws a warning as a result. You'll want to check `isset($action['controller'])` before doing the rest of your code that uses the controller variable.

Comment: It seems like Acelle's `AppServiceProvider` was designed poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved!!

**SOLUTION**:

creating a controller : MiwebController.php

```
<?
namespace Acelle\Http\Controllers;

class MiwebController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('lol');
    }
}
?>
```

routes.php:

```
Route::get('lol', 'MiwebController@index');
```

It works fine. Thank you!